# How to promote the usage of spring data

Tags: spring-data

Spring data offers a broad and popular set of standards for coding persistence faster. It's quite easier and readable than the old fashioned way with hard coded SQL scripts and row mappers...

Nevertheless Spring data is hard to promote to several companies as they complain about its potential performances issues in production. This argument is especially valid for highly demanding applications such as banking systems.

Apart the fast coding thing, I feel speechless when it comes to spring data performances. Please let me know it you have in mind some pros regarding spring data querying efficiency ;-)